# Why can't I use car inside this let statement in Scheme?

Tags: list, scheme, racket, sicp, cons

The following Scheme code works fine:

```
(define (same-parity x . numbers-input)
  (define (check-parity a) (= (remainder x 2) (remainder a 2)))
  (define (iter numbers-left)
    (cond ((null? numbers-left) nil)
          ((check-parity (car numbers-left)) (cons (car numbers-left) (iter (cdr numbers-left))))
          (else (iter (cdr numbers-left))))) 
  (cons x (iter numbers-input)))
```

It is supposed to output a list with the first element being an integer x and the subsequent elements being all the integers from numbers-input which have the same parity as x.

If anyone is interested, this is my attempt at solving the exercise 2.20 from the book [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%25_sec_2.2.1).

Now, I wanted to replace (car numbers-left) and (cdr numbers-left) with the variables "first" and "rest".

```
(define (same-parity x . numbers-input)
  (define (check-parity a) (= (remainder x 2) (remainder a 2)))
  (define (iter numbers-left)
    (let ((first (car numbers-left))
          (rest (cdr numbers-left)))
      (cond ((null? numbers-left) nil)
            ((check-parity first) (cons first (iter rest)))
            (else (iter rest))))) 
  (cons x (iter numbers-input)))
```

Trying to call this function now gives me an error:

```
> (same-parity 1 2 3 4 5)
. . mcar: contract violation
  expected: mpair?
  given: ()
```

Racket is highlighting the (car numbers-left) inside of the let-statement. Even when I never actually call "first" or "rest" in the body of the function and just leave it the way it was before, I get the same error.

However, in the following code I tried to copy the structure of the above procedure in a simple test definition and surprisingly, this works as you would expect.

```
(define (test x . testlist)
  (define (test2 test2list)
    (let ((first (car test2list)))
      first))
  (test2 testlist))

> (test 1 2 3 4 5)
2
```

It turns out that if I replace my (cond ...) in my original program with a simple call it works fine as well, so somehow the (cond ...) statement prohibits me from using the variables.

I know this is a very specific thing and I don't know if this ever really matters (except maybe if you want to make the code more readable) but I would really like to know why exactly it behaves this way.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables' values are evaluated as soon as you define them, whether you use them or not. Therefore you are calling `(car '())` at the end of your recursion, once the list has become empty. You never make it to the part of your `cond` that attempts to exit.